# Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors equivalent for asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core

How to prevent IIS from overriding custom error pages with IIS default error pages? Is there a Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors equivalent for asp.net core?
In ASP Net MVC I use the code below to send error without a custom page but in asp net core it is not working.

```cs
try
{
    // some code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
    mensagem = ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: What error page are you getting? Writing to the response body should be enough to avoid any of the default pages.

Comment: When the IIS get HTTP Status code 500 it send the custom error page. I don't want send this custom error page.

Comment: Have you tried following Introduction to [Error Handling in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling)?

Comment: I know how to create custom error page in asp net core, but I want in some cases not redirect to custom error pages. Example: i want return json with status code 404 instead custom 404 page.

Comment: As far as I understand you don't want to show an error page to users for specific HTTP status codes. Instead you want to return JSON in response. Is it correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to disable the status code error pages for a particular request. The [ASP.NET Core documentation for Handling Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-6.0#disable-status-code-pages) gives you the answer.

It's not as succinct as the old `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` flag, but may be clearer what's actually going on:

```cs
var statusCodePagesFeature =
    HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodePagesFeature>();

if (statusCodePagesFeature is not null)
{
    statusCodePagesFeature.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What you can try is writing an `exception` handling middleware. Here is a [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brandonh/2017/07/31/using-middleware-to-trap-exceptions-in-asp-net-core/) which I have used for reference. Something along the lines of

```cs
    public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
    {
      private readonly RequestDelegate next;

      public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
      {
        this.next = next;
      }

      public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
      {
        try
        {
            await next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await CustomHandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
      }

    private static Task CustomHandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {

        if (exception is NotFoundException)
        {

         var customJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new{ error = 
         exception.Message });
         context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
         context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
         return context.Response.WriteAsync(customJson);
       }
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't address the problem at all. IIS intercepts outbound responses that have status codes in the range 400-599 - you need to specify a special response header or side-channel to instruct IIS to not intercept and replace the response content. I believe this code works for you because you probably have a `web.config` rule so IIS doesn't replace HTTP 404 responses, but this won't work for 409, 5xx, etc.

Answer (score -2):

In controller:

```
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        return NotFound(new { Message = "Hello" });
    }
```

In web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <fileExtensions>
                <clear />
            </fileExtensions>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <httpErrors>
        <clear />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```